# Is there any efficient way to assign an id to cells while comparing two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to assign a specific ID serially to the data in df2 and based on that, ID I want to convert all its occurrences in df1. The code I have written takes a lot of time to execute. Is there any other way?

```
for i in range (0,35261):
    for j in range (0,54793):
        if (df2.V_ID[i] == df.V_ID[j]):
            df.V_ID[j] = i
```

sample data for df:

```
        time               IP1           IP2        GETVIDEO    V_ID                       IP3
0   2008-03-11 17:28:17 63.22.65.77 205.181.173.92  GETVIDEO    ORDhCi6JQaY&signature   254.212.25.169
1   2008-03-11 17:28:20 63.22.65.94 35.139.184.95   GETVIDEO    xEcFchOvj4Y&signature   254.212.19.255
2   2008-03-11 17:28:22 63.22.65.73 35.139.176.183  GETVIDEO    z-oBoCMSfbw&signature   254.212.19.196
3   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.73 102.15.230.123  GETVIDEO    pSo-_TavE1U&signature   254.212.25.206
4   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.77 102.15.134.225  GETVIDEO    kHtaORb0LUk&signature   254.212.22.122
5   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.77 102.15.111.222  GETVIDEO    t7qjlPPmeJE&origin  105.136.78.115
6   2008-03-11 17:28:27 63.22.65.73 35.139.31.8     GETVIDEO    2UPaRi0WY7c&origin  105.136.78.115
7   2008-03-11 17:28:28 63.22.65.73 102.15.143.68   GETVIDEO    lAzrUxpybs0&signature   254.212.21.130
8   2008-03-11 17:28:30 63.22.65.73 205.181.139.118 GETVIDEO    J_KKyw8V-l0&origin  105.136.78.115
9   2008-03-11 17:28:31 63.22.65.73 102.15.143.20   GETVIDEO    xnsPfRdSU0Q&origin  105.136.78.115
10  2008-03-11 17:28:34 63.22.65.94 102.15.141.151  GETVIDEO    qDKx6CkQM04&origin  105.136.78.115
```

sample data for df2 :

```
        V_ID            count
0   2UPaRi0WY7c&origin  768
1   t7qjlPPmeJE&origin  142
2   CKrTlXN9-iE&origin  107
3   IZtPejST9IQ&origin  103
4   FKb3qRljGBc&origin  93
5   LcM0OT6mnqA&origin  67
6   7sei-eEjy4g&origin  62
7   qDKx6CkQM04&origin  53
8   4rb8aOzy9t4&origin  46
9   wjv4Fp7GiGk&origin  46
10  SKDXBvPIepI&sign    44
```

Expected output:

```
time               IP1           IP2                    GETVIDEO    V_ID                       IP3
    0   2008-03-11 17:28:17 63.22.65.77 205.181.173.92  GETVIDEO    42  254.212.25.169
    1   2008-03-11 17:28:20 63.22.65.94 35.139.184.95   GETVIDEO    13  254.212.19.255
    2   2008-03-11 17:28:22 63.22.65.73 35.139.176.183  GETVIDEO    21  254.212.19.196
    3   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.73 102.15.230.123  GETVIDEO    14  254.212.25.206
    4   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.77 102.15.134.225  GETVIDEO    23  254.212.22.122
    5   2008-03-11 17:28:23 63.22.65.77 102.15.111.222  GETVIDEO    1   105.136.78.115
    6   2008-03-11 17:28:27 63.22.65.73 35.139.31.8     GETVIDEO    0   105.136.78.115
    7   2008-03-11 17:28:28 63.22.65.73 102.15.143.68   GETVIDEO    33  254.212.21.130
    8   2008-03-11 17:28:30 63.22.65.73 205.181.139.118 GETVIDEO    42  105.136.78.115
    9   2008-03-11 17:28:31 63.22.65.73 102.15.143.20   GETVIDEO    19  105.136.78.115
    10  2008-03-11 17:28:34 63.22.65.94 102.15.141.151  GETVIDEO    7   105.136.78.115
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Sure. Please help. @Sociopath

Comment: What do the ID's that you want to assign to df2 depend on? What conditions are used? Do you already have the Id's or do you want to assign the id's?

Comment: ID's are based on count values, in ascending order from df2 and once an ID is assigned I want to replace the video ID in df with the new IDs I recieved from df2.

Comment: You mean, if `2UPaRi0WY7c&origin` has occured 10 times, the id is 10. And then in df1 you want ot replace `2UPaRi0WY7c&origin` with 10. Is that right?

Comment: No. 2UPaRi0WY7c&origin index is 10 in df2 hence is replaced by 10 in df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'V_ID': ['a','b','c','d'], 'count':[12,5,7,9]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2008-03-11', '2008-03-11', '2008-03-11','2008-03-11', '2008-03-11', '2008-03-11', '2008-03-11'],
                   'V_ID': ['a', 'sdf', 'c','rge', 'gfg', 'a', 'a']})

# Create an index column for df2
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# Key-value pairs of index and V_ID
mapping = df2['V_ID'].to_dict()

# Invert key-value pairs 
mapping = {v: k for k, v in mapping.items()}

# Replace values in df['V_ID'] that matches with keys in mapping with values
df['V_ID'] = df['V_ID'].replace(mapping)

print(df)

         time V_ID
0  2008-03-11    0
1  2008-03-11  sdf
2  2008-03-11    2
3  2008-03-11  rge
4  2008-03-11  gfg
5  2008-03-11    0
6  2008-03-11    0
```

Comment: Can you please help me solve this error:

`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: @Shaswat_221b Is this an error you got when running the code i posted? Can you provide more information on how you get this error? Specifically the code you used to run and the line of code that caused this error. You can usually see this in the error trace.

Comment: `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    604 
    605                     if len(labels) != len(value):
--> 606                         raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
    607                                          'when setting with an iterable')
    608 

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: @Shaswat_221b you should specify the code on the line that raised this error. Not the line number.

Comment: Hmm that doesnt really tell me which line of code of causing the issue. Perhaps you can check out this post that had encountered the same error: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/pandas-apply-return-must-have-equal-len-keys-and-value-when-setting-with-an-ite

Comment: I think @Jan33 answer should answer this question.

Comment: Oh sorry!
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c25bb580c017> in <module>()
      5 
      6 matched_index = df2[df2.V_ID.isin(df.V_ID)].index.values
----> 7 df.loc[df.V_ID.isin(df2.V_ID), 'V_ID'] = matched_index
      8 df.head()`

Comment: Can you please recommend me the changes I need to make in my code according to [https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/pandas-apply-return-must-have-equal-len-keys-and-value-when-setting-with-an-ite]

Sorry to trouble you again. @MohitMotwani

Comment: Give me few mins. Working on it.

Comment: @Jan33 Since there are more than one occurrences, your code doesn't hold. the error comes out to be :

`shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)`

Comment: @Shaswat_221b I have made edits. Please check them out